# Add class to element if two parents share string of char in respective classes

Tags: jquery, css, regex, string

(I'm a beginner so please be indulgent and don't hesitate to ask for precisions.)

I want to add a class to an element if two of its parents appear to share a certain string of characters (below noted 'stringx') in their respective class names. But 'stringx' **can change** ('string1', 'string2', 'string3' 'string4'). Basically I need something that says : whatever 'stringx' is, it should be identical in these two parent elements.

For the moment, I have this code, awefully repeated four times (for 'string1' to 'string4').

```
$(function() {
    $(".archive.tax-['string1'] article .prefixe_['string1'] .prefixe_numerique").each(function() {
    if //some conditional 
    {
        $(this).parents("article").addClass("dom");
    }
    else{
        $(this).parents("article").addClass("sub");
    }

    });
});
```

And here is what the HTML looks like :

```
<body class="archive tax-string1"> <!--OR <body class="archive tax-string2">-->
 <article>
  <header>
   <div class="entry-meta">
    <p class="entry-title">
     <span class="prefixe_string1"> 
      <span class="prefixe_lettrique">C</span>
      <span class="prefixe_numerique">1.1</span>
     </span>
     <span class="prefixe_string2">
      <span class="prefixe_lettrique">︎</span>
      <span class="prefixe_numerique">2.</span>
     </span>
    </p> 
   </div>
  </header>
 </article>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you determine whether to call the class `string1` or `string2`, etc?

Comment: Can you add an example of how the HTML looks?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into advanced selectors within jQuery? 
In the example below, I'm looking for classes with a particular string and then applying a class to the children.

```
$('body[class*="tax-string"] span[class*="prefixe_string"]').children().addClass('className');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what `'string1'...'string4'` are you can use this iteration:

```
['string1','string2','string3','string4'].forEach(function(str){
    $(".archive.tax-" + str + " article .prefixe_" + str + " .prefixe_numerique").each(
        function() { ... }
    );
});
```

But that's lame. Let's make it generic:

```
$(".archive[class^="tax-"]").each(function(){ // select all relevant parent elements
    var tax = this.className.toString().match(/tax-(\S+)/);
    if (tax){
        tax = tax[1]; // get the "string1" thingie
        $(this).find('.prefixe_' + tax + ' .prefixe_numerique').each( // for every child element that match this specific "string1"
            function() { ... }
        );
    }
});
```

P.S: 
It looks like you want something like highlighting the current section in a menu according to current page. IMO there are better ways to get it done. For instance you can use "data-" attributes which, unlike css classes, are meant for custom strings.
This way you can get what you need easier and with a more readable code:

```
<body class="article" data-tax="string1">
 <article>
  <header>
   <div class="entry-meta">
    <p class="entry-title">
     <span class="prefixe_section" data-tax="string1"> 
      <span class="prefixe_lettrique">C</span>
      <span class="prefixe_numerique">1.1</span>
     </span>
     <span class="prefixe_section" data-tax="string2">
      <span class="prefixe_lettrique">︎</span>
      <span class="prefixe_numerique">2.</span>
     </span>
    </p> 
   </div>
  </header>
 </article>
</body>
```

And the JS part:

```
var current_tax = $('body').data('tax');
if (current_tax)
    $('.prefixe_section[data-tax="'+current_tax+'"] .prefixe_numerique').addClass('highlight');
```